# Mapping between Notations

Tags: ordinals

This is similar sounding to a question I asked quite recently on MO. However, the question asks something different. Hopefully someone will answer the question.

It is assumed that the (total) function describing a given notation is denoted as $address:p\rightarrow N$ and assumed to be bijective.

Suppose we are given two notations $N1$ and $N2$ for some $p \in \omega{_C}{_K}$(Church-Kleene). Denote the mapping from $N1$ to $N2$ as $P{_1}{_2}:N \rightarrow N$.

If we wanted to be more formal, we could say that consider the two functions $address1:p\rightarrow N$ and $address2:p\rightarrow N$ corresponding to $N1$ and $N2$ respectively. Then $P{_1}{_2}$ is defined by:
$$P{_1}{_2}(address1(x))=address2(x) \qquad for \; all \; x < p$$

Now assume that the less-than relations corresponding to $N1$ and $N2$ are computable. My question simply is the following: Is the function $P{_1}{_2}$ always equivalence-computable (computable using a program that has access to oracle deciding equivalence of ordinary programs)? If no, then what would be the example for it (also generally, what would be the suitable upper-bound in that case). If yes, then can someone give a reference where a proof(if there is one) for a reasonable upper-bound(or lack of it) is provided.

Edit: modified the question slightly

Comment: I have posted this question on mathoverflow, since there have been very few views after first few hours of posting. If you have an answer or interesting comment, kindly post it in this thread (to keep it in one place): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278045/mapping-between-notations.